# Foundation 6: how to include static css from package manager?

Tags: npm, gulp, zurb-foundation, bower

I'm loading a third party jquery plugin into foundation 6 via bower or npm.

I've included the javascript in `config.yml`, which works fine:

javascript:

```
   [...]
   - "bower_components/path/to/thirdpartyplugin.js"
```

But such plugins also bring basic **css** files I'd rather not copy, but include directly.

So where and how do I include them in order to be compiled (bundled) into `app.css`? Also, many plugins bring assets like an .svg or some .png – how do I get the compiler to copy them to the right location in `dist`?

Comment: did you try using an absolute import inside `/src/assets/scss/app.scss`? what happens then?

Comment: nothing; at least not in `/dist/assets/css/app.css`.

Comment: I've tried `@import '/bower_components/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';` and `@import 'owl.carousel.css';` to see if there was some auto-discovery mechanism

Comment: does the former work?

Comment: No. It's not a problem, as I can always include it old school, but I'd like to find out if there's a best practice with bower.

Comment: I've rephrased the entire question as I'm understanding it a bit better now

Comment: You could include the dependency into https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/gulp/javascript.js (JavaScript Gulp task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is not possible with the current foundation workflow. A solution would be to write an own gulp task that copies all assets from the components to /src/ and then compile them.

PS: Here's the workflow recommended by ZURB, http://zurb.com/university/lessons/adding-on-to-a-great-foundation – so also, copy-paste.